# GPS Coordinates and Direction

Tags: c#, xamarin, gps, compass-geolocation

I have a set of places of interest (addresses with their GPS coordinates) and would love to know which ones are in the direction I am facing.

That is, I would like to know (in real-time) which places from the list one could "see" if they looked in that direction. It will be based on a compass direction on a mobile device and the GPS coordinates of that device.

The solution will be a Xamarin mobile application in C#, but I would first like to know what the concept is called and how one would tackle such a challenge if they can get the current GPS coordinates and the direction.

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=compass%20ordinal%20between%20two%20gps%20coordinates%20c-sharp

Comment: I'd turn the compass direction into a heading (degrees). Then I'd add and subtract 45 or so degrees to create an arc to account for field of view. Then you just need to enumerate all of the points and see if the bearing from the observer to the point falls within that arc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will research that.

Comment: The alternative formula for course on this page (http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs) will probably work for you. Remember that this will calculate a "true heading", not a "magnetic heading", which is what you will get from the compass. I believe that you can get variation, which is the local difference between the two, from the GPS data.